# Programmatic invalidation of HttpSession

Tags: servlets, spring-security, tomcat7, httpsession

Is it possible to terminate a logged in user's HttpSession?

We can do the following from within the user's session:

```
HttpSession s = request.getSession(false);
s.invalidate(); // make sure s != null
```

But how can an Admin-User 'kick-out' a given user?

I was hoping to find some API under `ServletContext` which would return a list of active sessions, but that doesn't appear to be the case.

I'm using Spring Security 3 & Tomcat 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring Security has a [SessionRegistry](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/session/SessionRegistry.html) in order to handle this kind of scenarios. You can declare it using `session-registry-ref` attribute in `concurrency-control` tag. Here you have a little [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/session-mgmt.html).

Answer (score 3):

There are basically 2 ways (leaving Spring Security outside consideration as I don't do Spring):

1. Collect all those sessions in some application wide `Map<User, HttpSession>`. Then just do

   ```
   sessions.get(user).invalidate();
   ```

   The [`HttpSessionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html) and/or [`HttpSessionBindingListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionBindingListener.html) may be helpful in cleaning the application wide `Map` in case of session timeouts/expiration.
2. Add an boolean column to the DB which is checked on every request by some [filter](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info).

   ```
   if (shouldLogout(user)) {
       session.invalidate();
   }
   ```